# invalid use of non-static data member for a matrix building

Tags: c++

```
class Itembuilder
{
private:
    int numOfX;
    int numOfY;
    int numOfZ;
    int numOfSpc;
    int itemMatrix [numOfZ][numOfY][numOfX];
public:
    void build (Space spc, Item item)
    {
        numOfX = item.getX()/spc.getX(); //number of space requirement for X origin
        numOfY = item.getY()/spc.getY(); //number of space requirement for Y origin
        numOfZ = item.getZ()/spc.getZ(); //number of space requirement for Z origin

        for (int layer=1; layer<=numOfZ; layer++) // stating layers of item through Z origin
        {
            for (int orgY=1; orgY<=numOfY; orgY++) // stating origin Y of a layer
            {
                for (int orgX=1; orgX<=numOfX; orgX++) // stating origin X
                {
                    itemMatrix[layer][orgY][orgX]=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Hi, I'm very new to coding in C++. I'm trying to build 3D item for allocating in a domain. First, I got "item.get" and "spc.get" variables from other classes. When trying to state the units as 0 with itemMatrix, I got error about non-static condition of private variables. How would I state space units with matrix?

Please correct my codes with proper one

Thanks

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the actual error text.  Paraphrasing tends to lose important details.

Comment: Your problem is that the compiler cannot determine the size of an object. Use `std::vector`

Comment: A warning: arrays in C++ go from `0` to `size - 1` for an array of `int x[size]`. Thus, your `for` loops start late and go too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int itemMatrix[numOfZ][numOfY][numOfX];
```

C++ does not allow you to use values of member variables in declaring other members.

The process of creating a 3D matrix from arrays is a lot simpler if you use nested vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> itemMatrix;
```

Then you can initialize it in the constructor as follows:

```
Itembuilder(int numOfX, int numOfY, int numOfZ)
:   itemMatrix(numOfX, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(numOfY, std::vector<int>(numOfZ))) {
}
```

> Is there any other way to initialize vector instead of constructor?

The vector needs to be initialized in the constructor in order to make the object consistent upon construction. However, it does not mean that you don't have an option to re-assign the vector once the constructor has finished. If you later need to change the matrix, for example, to change its size, you can re-assign the vector:

```
void changeSize(int numOfX, int numOfY, int numOfZ) {
    itemMatrix = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>(
        numOfX
    ,   std::vector<std::vector<int>>(numOfY, std::vector<int>(numOfZ))
    );
}
```

Comment: Oops - Did not think it through

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for comment but if I initialize the vector via constructor, I cannot call the class again in main() in order to make sure the correctness of my script. Is there any other way to initialize vector instead of constructor. I also need to assign values after creating 3d matrix. I'm stuck with this point